# Редактирование файлов .docx с помощью js

Tags: javascript, docx

Проблема такая: есть файл шаблона `.docx` мне нужно средствами ***js*** заменить в нём метки.

Например в документе есть метка **`{{name}}`** которую я заменяю на например **Иван**.

Хотелось бы что бы файл шаблона оставался не тронутым, а создавался новый файл со всеми изменениями.

Comment: Попробуйте найти готовую библиотеку и написать решение с ее применением.
Или .docx можно раз-zip-овать и работать, как с текстовыми файлами.

Comment: На клиентском `js` такого не добиться... Только серверный `js - node.js`

Comment: Формат docx - закрытый. Найти для него opensource библиотеку на js почти невозможно. Единственный вариант - парсить ручками, но без знания спецификации это больно.